# When adding JavaScript data to a page what's more efficient: creating new elements or populating existing ones?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page where I'm adding API response data by creating new HTML elements with the data.

Should I be creating my HTML elements on the page and get them via my script then populate them?

Is it less efficient to create them in the JS or does it not matter?

Thanks

Comment: I would also suggest that if you are receiving data from a server that you might as well send the html to go with that data rather than building up the elements on the client and injecting the chunk of html.

Comment: I personally try to reuse DOM elements whenever possible, but given a complex enough DOM, unless you have a strong logical association between your JavaScript code and DOM elements, it can be cumbersome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the contents of an element, or appending an element?

Both cases requires a redraw in most cases, so the right answer is probably that the most efficient solution if you need to change many elements, would be to create those elements in a [documentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createDocumentFragment), and append them all to the DOM in one go, instead of changing the contents of many elements already existing in the DOM, requiring a redraw for each manipulation.

As a sidenote, cloning elements is faster than creating new ones.

Comment: Why would it require a redraw for each *manipulation*?

Comment: @Ian - because new DOM elements cause invalidation of the drawing surface

Comment: @ian - Unless the elements are hidden, changing any part of the elements appearance would trigger a redraw, how else would you see the changed content ?

Comment: @JoshE Yeah but it wouldn't require a redraw for **every** manipulation, just **every** execution cycle. It's not like a redraw happens every time you use something like `.appendChild()`, does it? It'll happen after they calls are done and the Javascript is done executing...which would be once

Comment: Because of the blocking nature of JavaScript, the redraw shouldn't happen until the entire function is complete. It would be a different case of course if this is being done in asynchronous chunks.

Comment: @squint Exactly. I was thinking, if for some crazy reason, all the manipulations were done with `setTimeout` (or the likes), that it would obviously cause a redraw each time. But since they would (**could**) all be within the same execution, it would happen once. At the same time, maybe I was misunderstanding something

Comment: Can you confirm that it will only redraw once after the current javascript has executed? Would be useful to know as in my experience relying on this makes pages laggy, while using a document fragment makes them much faster.

Comment: @Ian: Yeah, I think your comments were spot on.

Comment: I don't know when specifically a browser redraw is done, I guess it depends on what you change, what browser, and a lot of other things, but documentFragments have proven to be a lot faster as you would insert the content only once, so something surely is happening when appending multiple elements with methods like appendChild, and I believe [John's testing](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/) showed it to be almost three times faster.

Comment: @Ally I know jQuery uses document fragments when you append HTML strings, so I trust it's faster. I'm not sure why though. But try looping from 1 to 99999999, appending a new div (with content) to the DOM each time - you won't see 1 div being added at a time. Instead, your browser will freeze for several seconds and all 99999999 will be shown at once. To me, that means a redraw happens once per execution cycle (if it's needed). The loop is synchronous and is what causes the single execution cycle, compared to `setTimeout` which causes several (and therefore several redraws).

Comment: @Ally: There may be some other optimizations experienced when using a document fragment, but I don't think the redraw necessarily comes into play. If one were to create a demo that does some DOM updates, but intentionally implements slow running code that blocks, you'll see that the redraw doesn't happen until the function is complete.

Comment: @adeneo Absolutely. I guess I was just questioning the wording, because to me, a redraw isn't happening every manipulation. I'm just wondering what the true reason is why document fragments improve this. I'll read that article from Resig and maybe it explains it

Comment: @Ian - if I remember correctly, I read something somewhere about a redraw being triggered everytime an element changes in such a way that it affects other elements on the page. Considering all the optimization in newer browsers, and redraws being one of the most expensive operations, you would think they would find a way to limit redraws to an absolute minimum. At the same time, the more redraws, the more responsive the browser seems? Changing the innerHTML of several elements already on the page will be a lot slower than just appending a bunch of elements in one go, that's for sure!

Comment: A web browser needs to queue for system resources just like any other application, and is still subject to the whims of the OS in render and scheduling terms. Simply moving your mouse cursor over a DOM element may cause that part of the render buffer to be invalidated; I think the actual question at hand is what would trigger the **browser** to perform a layout/re-render operation. That can happen anytime a DOM element is changed.

Answer (score 1):

A good analogy I think is in terms of how we approach the question of string concatenation vs. building (.NET/C# if you want something more specific).

We're told that string concatenation is not an efficient operation, since a new string must be created and allocated for each binary string expression (`var a = "foo" + " " + " bar"` necessitates the creation of no less than `4!` separate objects on the heap - someone correct me if I'm wrong on that one). So we use instead a `StringBuilder` object which batches up string operations until asked for a full string.

Similarly, modifications to the DOM force browsers to re-traverse every node as part of the computation of the new tree. There are optimizations that I'm sure every browser takes advantage of, but there's no way to avoid the fact that the larger and more complex (nested) a DOM is, the more expensive a traversal operation will be. Re-using existing DOM nodes can be considered analogous to using a `StringBuilder` for heavy string concatenation.

Minimizing the number of times a browser needs to re-visit DOM nodes can significantly speed up performance of operations involving the addition or deletion of nodes.

That said, similar "rules of thumb" as apply to string concatenation should be applied:

- if the tree or the number of operations is small, don't sweat it
- if performance is the issue, profile first to ensure the problem is what
  you think it is
- if you have a lot of minor changes, batch them together
- avoid trying to solve a problem that isn't present
- the reusal of (DOM) objects has potential to add significant complexity. Make sure you understand this cost to help determine whether it's worth it or not.